# image in SVG's image tag displays in Desktop browser, not iphone

Tags: html, svg

I have got a site up and running, here's the issue I observe, you can look at it on: https://www.roadmapedia.com/roadmap/5c849cbd78487700173a172a

In the blue screen part with the treemap like thing, the images display perfectly fine assuming that you are on Desktop.

However, it looks like this on my iphone6: [image]

So the SVG images are not displaying. 
Here's the SVG images in code:

```
<image xlink:href="/static/media/circle.ffe52f1d.png" height="60" transform="translate(-30,-30)"></image>
```

The image tag is wrapped inside of a SVG tag. So actually after all, I am displaying a png inside of a image tag of a SVG.

There's a question with the same title as mine on SO, but it is asking something different.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You may notice that your image also appears incorrectly on Safari. Especially where transforms and special cases are concerned, not all SVG renderers follow the SVG standard behavior.

On Safari I was able to fix your problem by adding a `width="60"` to both the PNG you mention in your question and the YouTube SVG that also appears in the image. The YouTube SVG also appears to fail on mobile and Safari.

According to the Safari Web Inspector, the reason the images aren't showing up is because the width is getting calculated at "1px".

**So in summary, add `width` attributes. Try changing the PNG `image` tag to this**

```
<image xlink:href="/static/media/circle.ffe52f1d.png" width="60" height="60" transform="translate(-30,-30)"></image>
```

**and the SVG `image` tag to this.**

```
<image xlink:href="/static/media/youtube.45edfe4d.svg" width="60" height="60" transform="translate(-30,-30)"></image>
```

and the problem should be fixed, though I have no way of testing this on a mobile device without an undue amount of work.

#### P.S.

The PNG you're using in the image is extremely simple. It seems to be just a circle with a linear color gradient. I would highly recommend vectorizing it instead of using a raster image within your SVG. It would be a very simple SVG file to create.

Comment: @Acy happy to help. Feel free to email me at william@coinflip.tech if you need help with the vectorizing.